# InstallShield LE 1001 Error / Installing Windows Service on Windows XP

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-services, setup-project, installshield-le

I got a 1001 error and had fight a lot against it using InstallShield LE (Visual Studio 2013) to deploy a simple Windows Service on Windows XP.

Sometimes the error happened, sometimes not.

Comment: I was having this problem also and I actually found the exact setting you have to change in InstallShield LE. I wrote it up how to fix it at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32949860/error-1001-when-installing-custom-windows-service/38269757#38269757

Answer (score 9):

And finally I found the cause:
My Services.msc window was opened, and when I uninstall the service it get "marked for deletion" but the window holds the service there until I close it.

So, close the services.msc window while reinstalling the service, to avoid this lock problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Windows Service install created on Win7 with InstallShield LE, VS 2015, and installed on a Win Sever 2012 machine.  In my case, the error was due to two different things on the installing user's part:

- An incorrect password and
- Failure to include the domain name (domain\UserName) in the user name field of the credentials dialog.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I am using VS2012 and InstallShield LE

I was also facing the very same issue. In my case, the service was not removed from the Service.msc window. It appears that the registry was not fully cleaned when I previously uninstalled it (from Add/Remove Programs).

Then I tried the below command.
    SC DELETE 
Then it cleared all the stray registry entries, and this time the installation went through fine.

Below is the help on this command (taken from the SC help on Command prompt)
     delete----------Deletes a service (from the registry).